# enumerating apache directory versions using .net

Tags: c#, .net, directory-structure, enumerate

I am trying to enumerate the file system, checking for apache versions installed in wamp. The apache folder usually has the version numbers in the name.

My goal is first to look for this folder in each drive

```
2.2.19
2.2.18
2.2.1
2.2.0
```

so the file path can look like `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.20` or `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.1`

How do I check if this folder exists and also get the version from the folder name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Directory.GetDirectories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) to get all directories.

Something like this should work for you:

```
var directory = @"C:\wamp\bin\apache\";
foreach(var dir in Directory.GetDirectories(directory)) {
    var version = dir.Replace(directory, "")
                     .Replace("Apache", "");

    Console.WriteLine("{0} is installed", version);
}
```

Comment: Also, `Directory.GetLogicalDrives()` to get the drives.

Comment: does the get directories accept Wild car parameters like the Getfiles does? So that i can pass somthing like get `GetDirectories(directory, like apache[0-9.])

Comment: @Smith Yes, there is an Directory.GetDirectories(directory, searchPattern) overload which accepts a pattern. See MSDN for ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w.aspx